# I try to access the array elements but get undefined

Tags: javascript

I cannot access the elements of the array. I have not put the whole code because it is too long but I explain what I have done.

I have an array *results* of the following type:

`results [i] = myArr.Items [i]`

or so done:

```js
{3: {...}, 4: {...}, 9: {...}}
3: {type: 'Image', id_a: '123456', value: 'moto_guzzi_v100_mandello.jpg', number: 3, id: 3}
4: {type: 'Text', id_a: '123456', value: 'The star of the Piaggio group stand is without doubt ... Discover all her secrets with our video', number: 2, id: 2}
9: {type: 'Text', id_a: '123456', value: 'The V100 Mandello celebrates the 100th anniversary of the house and… ovative. Let's find out together with our video. ', Number: 4, id: 4}
```

and I'm trying to recover the items as shown in the code below:

```js
Object.entries(results).forEach(function (item) {               
                    let child = document.createElement("tr");
                    child.innerHTML = `
                    <td>${item.number}</td>
                    <td>${item.type}</td>
                    <td>${item.value}</td>
                    table.appendChild(child);
                })
```

```html
   <table id="my-table" width="90%">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                    </tr>
            
                </table>
```

I just get the value `undefined` for each value.

Can anyone kindly explain to me the correct way to access these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object.entries() makes your object list iterable, but if you console.log each `item` you'll see its an array with 2 entries - the index (0) and the data (1)

```js
let results = {
  3: {
    type: 'Image',
    id_a: '123456',
    value: 'moto_guzzi_v100_mandello.jpg',
    number: 3,
    id: 3
  },
  5: {
    type: 'Text',
    id_a: '123456',
    value: 'The star of the Piaggio group stand is without doubt ... Discover all her secrets with our video',
    number: 2,
    id: 2
  },
  8: {
    type: 'Text',
    id_a: '123456',
    value: 'The V100 Mandello celebrates the 100th anniversary of the house and… ovative. Let\'s find out together with our video. ',
    Number: 4,
    id: 4
  }
};

Object.entries(results).forEach(item => {
  item = item[1];
  let child = document.createElement("tr");
  child.innerHTML = `
                    <td>${item.number}</td>
                    <td>${item.type}</td>
                    <td>${item.value}</td>`
  document.querySelector('#my-table').appendChild(child);
})
```

```html
<table id="my-table" width="90%" border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Object.entries`. The correct form of iterating over your array is:

```
for (const i in results) {
    const item = results[i];    
    let child = document.createElement("tr");
    child.innerHTML = `
    <td>${item.number}</td>
    <td>${item.type}</td>
    <td>${item.value}</td>
    table.appendChild(child);
}
```